# Falha ao customizar a tab do javafx, borda superior do painel não aparece

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

Gostaria que a área do TabPanel que não tivesse tab ficasse com uma borda conforme a imagem abaixo.

Atualmente meu TabPanel está assim, sem borda à direita de "Enter"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ficasse assim, mas não sei onde colocar instrução da borda, sem  colocar borda também no que está selecionado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o meu código de estilo:

```
.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
.tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
}
.tab-pane
{
    -fx-tab-min-width:90px;
}

.tab{
    -fx-background-insets: 0 1 0 1,0,0;
    -fx-min-width: 120px;
    -fx-min-height: 23px;
    -fx-border-width:  1 1 0 0;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: #dbe2e8;
    -fx-padding: 7 20 7 20;
}
.tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}

.tab-pane .tab:selected
{
    -fx-background-color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill:  #7d97ad;
    -fx-font-family: Arial;
}

.tab:selected .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-text-fill: #96b946;
}
```

Estou aprendendo agora, então sou bem leigo em JavaFx.

Comment: tira do teu código o style para `.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background`

Comment: @JulioCesar alterei o estilo no lugar de tirar e funcionou, era exatamente ali que eu tinha que mexer

Answer (score 2):

Deve ser alterado no estilo onde está:

```
.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

Para o código abaixo

```
   .tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
        -fx-background-color: #ffffff; /* Altera a cor do plano de fundo do header para a mesma cor do fundo da aplicação */
        -fx-border-color:  #dbe2e8; /* Define a cor da borda para a mesma cor da borda das abas *?
        -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;  /* Define que a borda inferior terá 1 px (top, left, bottom, right) */
    }
```

Dessa forma o sistema irá tornar a área de fundo do header do tab a mesma da aplicação, dando a impressão que sumiu, porém a borda de baixo ainda vai existir e o layout ficou certo.